# Can't figure out why this is causing an infinite loop

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, logic, infinite-loop

So I have this line of code where it keeps generating an infinite loop every now and then.  Is my logic incorrect somewhere?  The if statement inside of "if (randomNumbersForSelectionArray.Count > 0)" should always return true, but it doesn't.  Then when I do an else statement and check to see if the code should be true when it goes into an infinite loop, it confirms that my logic should be correct.  I can't seem to figure out where this is going wrong.  Thanks!!

---

***Here is some sample output that I'm getting.***

12| 2 =should= 2
Why is this breaking!?!?!?
12| 2 =should= 2
Why is this breaking!?!?!?
*...for infinite*

---

int countLoop = 0;

if (trackFitnessRankArray.Length >= 1)
{

```
            while (randomNumbersForSelectionArray.Count > 0)
            {
                countLoop++;

                for (int j = trackFitnessRankArray.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    if (randomNumbersForSelectionArray.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (randomNumbersForSelectionArray[0] >= (trackFitnessRankArray[j].CutoffPointForReproduction - trackFitnessRankArray[j].ChanceOfReproduction) && randomNumbersForSelectionArray[0] < trackFitnessRankArray[j].CutoffPointForReproduction)
                        {
                            //take the selected AIs and put them in an array
                            selectedToBreed.Add(trackFitnessRankArray[j]);

                            //remove the number from the randomNumber array
                            randomNumbersForSelectionArray.RemoveAt(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //if we're in an infinite loop
                            if (countLoop > AI_IN_EACH_GENERATION)
                            {
                                if (randomNumbersForSelectionArray[0] == trackFitnessRankArray[j].CutoffPointForReproduction)
                                {
                                    if (j != 0)
                                        Debug.WriteLine(j + "| " + randomNumbersForSelectionArray[0] + " =should= " + (trackFitnessRankArray[j - 1].CutoffPointForReproduction + trackFitnessRankArray[j - 1].ChanceOfReproduction));
                                    if (randomNumbersForSelectionArray[0] != (trackFitnessRankArray[j - 1].CutoffPointForReproduction + trackFitnessRankArray[j - 1].ChanceOfReproduction))
                                        Debug.WriteLine("Why is this breaking!?!?!?");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The component

```
//remove the number from the randomNumber array
                            randomNumbersForSelectionArray.RemoveAt(0);
```

should be out of the if